# jQuery function to scroll page to selected heading using keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this bit of code to create a list of all the `h2` elements in a page with clickable links, but it isn't usable with a keyboard.

I want to be able to select the `this` referenced in the code and scroll down to it by pressing enter on the keyboard.

Does anyone know how I could do this? Cheers

```js
if (jQuery(sections).length > 1) {
  jQuery(sections).each(function() {
    sectionList += '<li class="scrollControl"><span class="sectionText" tabindex="0">' + jQuery(this).html() + "</span></li>";
  });
```

Comment: There is no scrolling here. Can you post a [mcve] using the snippet editor `[<>]`

Comment: It's not clear what you want. There are no clickable links. And what do you mean with "*select the 'this' referenced in the code*"?

Comment: one of the `$(sections)` is the `$(this)`

Comment: Please see updated answer for an ENTER addition

Answer (score 0):

You mean this

Here I ALSO allow tabbing and enter on the LI

```js
const $sections = $("h1");
$("#nav").html(
  $sections.map(function() {
    return `<li class="scrollControl"><span class="sectionText" tabindex="0">${$(this).html()}</span></li>`
  }).get().join("")
);
$("#nav").on("click", "li", function() {
  $sections.eq($(this).index())[0].scrollIntoView()
})
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.code === "Enter") {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("li")
    if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("scrollControl" )) {
      $sections.eq($(tgt).index())[0].scrollIntoView()
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav"></ul>
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<h1>Section 2</h1>
```